# Difference between git inside Visual Studio 2013 standalone git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer

I have a project where integrated Team Explorer inside Visual Studio 2013 changes seems caused by see line ending(if I am using diff compare from within VS, it shows line ending difference only), but inside git (2.14) command line, `git diff` shows nothing. The remote origin repo is from Visual Studio Team Service, but I wouldn't  don't think whether that makes any difference?

After a bit of research, it seems that VS 2013 is using LibGit2, which might explain what's cause the difference. Is there anyway I can ask VS 2013, especially team explorer to ignore line ending/white space difference in term of change detection? I would expect that VS 2013 are following same global/project git configuration, so what's the difference?

After realising that it is a line ending issue, I checked `core.autocrlf` in my git congif which is true. and tried to add a .gitattributes with `text=auto`, then realised that all **those correct configs are probably the reason that I am starting to get line ending changes only?** What I really want to do is probably either make sure git in VS 2013 ignore those changes, or undo those changes, and hopefully there will be no more those kind of changes flagged inside VS only. Unfortunately following the command by command in section "Refreshing a repository after changing line endings" from [this github help article](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) doesn't seems working for me, and I don't really understand how it should work either. So I am still hoping I can some how make git inside VS 2013 behave properly. Is there any way I can check the version or update git inside VS 2013?

**Update**
My previously suspect about it has to be something to do with line ending/white-space doesn't make sense anymore, as I just realized that **at lease `git diff` should not ignoring white-space/line ending, and it does not show anything at all**. So what's going on?

Comment: Yes, VS 2013 uses libgit2/libgit2sharp.  VS 2017 has made the switch to use Git for Windows for consistency with the command line.  Have you tried using a .gitattributes file in your repo to dictate the EOL conversion behavior?

Comment: @ChadB, please see my the update of my question, I've the last paragraph about what else I did checked/tried. I think that my config and .gitattributes are not the problem as far as line ending issue concerned, as they seems all right and might be the reason that I have new changes introduced?